# Q_PROPERTY System not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I have this class I intended to use in the context of a qml engine so in order to use property binding I setted up these Q_PROPERY macros. I want to use the MEMBER keyword and have the notify signal emitted automatically.

```
class InterfaceBackend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(quint8 current_view MEMBER m_current_view NOTIFY sCurrentViewChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(quint8 future_view MEMBER m_future_view NOTIFY sFutureViewChanged)

public:
    explicit InterfaceBackend(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~InterfaceBackend();

    quint8 getCurrentView() { return this->m_current_view; }
    quint8 getFutureView() { return this->m_future_view; }

private:
    quint8 m_current_view;
    quint8 m_future_view;
    QByteArray m_selected_language;

public slots:
    void onLanguageSelected(QByteArray language);

private slots:


signals:
    void sCurrentViewChanged(quint8 current_view);
    void sFutureViewChanged(quint8 future_view);

};


InterfaceBackend::InterfaceBackend(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->setObjectName("backend");
    QObject::connect(this, &InterfaceBackend::sFutureViewChanged, []() {qDebug() << "sFutureViewChanged";});
    this->m_current_view=1;
    this->m_future_view=1;
}

InterfaceBackend::~InterfaceBackend()
{

}

void InterfaceBackend::onLanguageSelected(QByteArray language)
{
    this->m_selected_language=language;
    this->m_future_view=2;
}
```

qt docs say:

*A NOTIFY signal is optional. If defined, it should specify one existing signal in that class that is emitted whenever the value of the property changes. NOTIFY signals for MEMBER variables must take zero or one parameter, which must be of the same type as the property. The parameter will take the new value of the property. The NOTIFY signal should only be emitted when the property has really been changed, to avoid bindings being unnecessarily re-evaluated in QML, for example. Qt emits automatically that signal when needed for MEMBER properties that do not have an explicit setter*

But whenever I call the slot the signals never gets called nor the property is updated in the qml model, what's wrong!?

Comment: try to remove getters. MEMBER keyword automatically creates getter and setter for property

Comment: commented out getters (wich are not included in the macros) still not working, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

To give an answer that is technically more accurate:

The `MEMBER` in `Q_PROPERTY` will tell the moc (Meta object compiler) that when accessing the property *via the meta object* it should use the member directly instead of a getter or setter method. So the moc will the generate a setter method internally that sets the member **and** emits the signal - it basically just does the work of writing getters/setters for you. Since changing a member needs to emit the change signal, this is automatically done when the property is written from the *meta object system*. So, calling:

```
backend->setProperty("future_view", future_view);
```

will correctly emit the changed signal. This is the only guarantee that is given when using MEMBER. Changes, that are done via the meta property will trigger the change signal. This means if you would set `future_view` from QML directly, without the `onLanguageSelected` method, it would actually work.

In your example however you directly write a value to the member inside a special method - This will not trigger the signal automatically! (I mean, how should Qt even know you did that). So what you need to do is whenever you change the value of your member you need to emit the change signal yourself:

```
void onLanguageSelected(QByteArray language)
{
    this->m_selected_language=language;
    this->m_future_view=2;
    emit sFutureViewChanged();
}
```

---

**Edit:** If you were trying prevent the properties from beeing written directly from QML, using `MEMBER` will not work! Use a getter instead and only register the getter with the property. Use the same code as above to write and change the properties:

```
    Q_PROPERTY(quint8 future_view READ futureView NOTIFY sFutureViewChanged)
```

Comment: this is clarifying indeed, say C++ side is ok, but in QML if I bind the propery current_view like: "property int current_view: backend.current_view" and QML edits this property, back in C++ I receive only the signal onCurrentViewChanged but the variable does not get updated!!

Comment: QML-Bindings are unidirectional. Changes to `backend.current_view` will update the QML property, but not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in [this](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.1) article:

> New keyword in Q_PROPERTY: MEMBER let you bind a property to a class member without requiring to have a getter or a setter.

So you should remove your getters, and your result code will look like this

```
class InterfaceBackend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(quint8 current_view MEMBER m_current_view NOTIFY sCurrentViewChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(quint8 future_view MEMBER m_future_view NOTIFY sFutureViewChanged)

public:
    explicit InterfaceBackend(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QObject(parent)
    {
        this->setObjectName("backend");
        QObject::connect(this, &InterfaceBackend::sFutureViewChanged, []() { qDebug() << "sFutureViewChanged";});
        this->m_current_view=1;
        emit sCurrentViewChanged();
        this->m_future_view=1;
        emit sFutureViewChanged();
    }
    ~InterfaceBackend() = default;

private:
    quint8 m_current_view;
    quint8 m_future_view;
    QByteArray m_selected_language;

public slots:
    void onLanguageSelected(QByteArray language) {
        this->m_selected_language=language;
        this->m_future_view=2;
        emit sFutureViewChanged();
    }

signals:
    void sCurrentViewChanged();
    void sFutureViewChanged();

};
```

Comment: Removing getters won't do any difference as they are not referenced in the macros with READ or WRITE, also this is NOT what i want, emitting manually change signal works well (I tried before posting) BUT as I understand (if I'm not wrong) using MEMBER will automatically emit the signal in FACT it WON'T and the problem is here

Comment: If you change property from qml it will automaticaly emits signal. But if you change property's value form c++ side it won't emit any signal.

Comment: Ok I fugured out I have to use setProperty() to emit signal auto in C++, but if I change it form qml it does not emit the signal, why?

Comment: No, sorry IT DOES emit the signal, but it does NOT update the member variable, it is not clear at all the behavior of this property system to me even if I read the documentation extensively...

Comment: Ok. If i get it right
 1) you use ``` setProperty("current_view", 1) ``` instead of ```  this->m_current_view=1;
        emit sCurrentViewChanged(); ``` in c++
2) you move instance of your object ot qml and use it in qml
as possible solution: try to inherit your class from QQuickItem, register it and import  in qml. After that create instance in qml and try to use this property

Answer (score -1):

Every Q_PROPERTY must have READ public method and WRITE public slot, also the signal will never automatically emited, you should emit it whenever MEMBER change.

```
class InterfaceBackend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(quint8 current_view MEMBER m_current_view READ currentView WRITE setCurrentView NOTIFY sCurrentViewChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(quint8 future_view MEMBER m_future_view READ futureView WRITE setFutureView NOTIFY sFutureViewChanged)

public:
    explicit InterfaceBackend(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~InterfaceBackend();

    quint8 currentView() const
    {
        return m_current_view;
    }
    quint8 futureView() const
    {
        return m_future_view;
    }

private:
    quint8 m_current_view;
    quint8 m_future_view;
    QByteArray m_selected_language;

public slots:
    void onLanguageSelected(QByteArray language);

    void setCurrentView(quint8 current_view)
    {
        if (m_current_view == current_view)
            return;

        m_current_view = current_view;
        emit sCurrentViewChanged(m_current_view);
    }

    void setFutureView(quint8 future_view)
    {
        if (m_future_view == future_view)
            return;

        m_future_view = future_view;
        emit sFutureViewChanged(m_future_view);
    }

private slots:


signals:
    void sCurrentViewChanged(quint8 current_view);
    void sFutureViewChanged(quint8 future_view);

};


InterfaceBackend::InterfaceBackend(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->setObjectName("backend");
    QObject::connect(this, &InterfaceBackend::sFutureViewChanged, []() {qDebug() << "sFutureViewChanged";});
    this->m_current_view=1;
    this->m_future_view=1;
}

InterfaceBackend::~InterfaceBackend()
{

}

void InterfaceBackend::onLanguageSelected(QByteArray language)
{
    this->m_selected_language=language;
    this->m_future_view=2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Spending some time, I got it working as I need, althought this is EXTREMELY UGLY and BY NO MEANS DECLARATIVE I think it is the only way to achive double binding, and maybe it will be helpful for other people approaching the problem. Note this is not an accepted answer, I still hope someone somewhere, perhaps in the future if and when Qt will be updated, could come up with a far more elegant solution.

Main disadvantages: longer and verbose code, one has to use setters everywhere and (try not forget)

The property system doesn't do anything automatically in the end, just states wich properties are exposed and wich are their getters/setters and change signals

c++

```
class InterfaceController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(quint8 current_view READ getCurrentView WRITE setCurrentView NOTIFY sCurrentViewChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(quint8 future_view READ getFutureView WRITE setFutureView NOTIFY sFutureViewChanged)

public:
    explicit InterfaceController(QObject *parent = 0);

    //getters
    quint8 getCurrentView() { return this->m_current_view; }
    quint8 getFutureView() { return this->m_future_view; }

    //setters
    Q_INVOKABLE void setCurrentView(quint8 current_view) { if(this->m_current_view!=current_view) {this->m_current_view=current_view; emit sCurrentViewChanged(this->m_current_view);} }
    Q_INVOKABLE void setFutureView(quint8 future_view) { if(this->m_future_view!=future_view) {this->m_future_view=future_view; emit sFutureViewChanged(this->m_future_view);} }

private:
    quint8 m_current_view;
    quint8 m_future_view;

    QByteArray m_selected_language;

public slots:
    void onLanguageSelected(QByteArray language);

private slots:


signals:
    void sCurrentViewChanged(quint8 current_view);
    void sFutureViewChanged(quint8 future_view);

};

InterfaceController::InterfaceController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->m_current_view=1;
    this->m_future_view=1;
}

void InterfaceController::onLanguageSelected(QByteArray language)
{
    this->m_selected_language=language;
    this->setFutureView(2);
}
```

QML

```
id: root
property int current_view: 1
property int future_view: 1

Connections {
    target: root
    onCurrent_viewChanged: { backend.setCurrentView(current_view); }
    onFuture_viewChanged: { backend.setFutureView(future_view); }
}

Connections {
    target: backend
    onSCurrentViewChanged: { if(root.current_view!=current_view) {root.current_view=current_view;} }
    onSFutureViewChanged: { if(root.future_view!=future_view) {root.future_view=future_view;} }
}
```